# Codename One - Designer auto up-scales images

Tags: codenameone, designer

I have a background image added to the designer as a multi image. the image is good enough in quality that I removed the "high" scaled version of it manually, in doing:

Designer -> All images -> click on my image -> from the **DPI** dropdown, choose the highest resolution -> click **Delete**.

Problem now is, every time I save anything in the designer, it automatically recreates this scaled version for me. This resolution takes up too much space and I want a lean app.

How can I prevent the automated recreated of scaled images, that I purposely removed?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the designers XML mode which I thought we fixed. Delete the content of the res directory (except for the guibuilder directory if you have it) then delete the unneeded DPI from the res file again and save again. It should remove the file permanently now and recreate the contents of the res folder.